# Autofac. IoC container with parameters. Best practices

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

After studing the [Autofac documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/parameters.html), and some stackoverflow questions

[Best Practices for IOC Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480286/best-practices-for-ioc-container),

[IoC Container. Inject container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40548487/ioc-container-inject-container)

I understand that I need put container on highes level,and after that pass it thrue needed classes.

f.ex I have high level class controller

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserManager userManager;
    public AccountController(IUserManager userManager) //I configure Global.asax and there will 
    {                                                  //be UserManager class. OK.
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }
}
```

on lower level I have UserManager class whit parameter IUnitOfWork. Should I put there new UnitOfWork instance or do it with some container?

```
public class UserManager : IUserManager
{
    readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public UserManager (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

Piece of autofac configuration.

```
conteinerBuilder.RegisterType<UserManager>().As<IUserManager>()
            .WithParameter("unitOfWork",new UnitOfWork()) //This is what bothers me
                                                          //Like I understand we wanna 
                                                          //work with abstraction not with some 
                                                          //implementations but there I must use 
                                                          //UnitOfWork
```

Tell me which way to dig, I'm completely confused. 
I'll be greateful for any help. =)

Comment: Just register your type and it will by default resolve the constructor arguments for you. Since you're new to IoC, you might want to watch this super handy video: [Deep Dive Into Dependency Injection And Writing Decoupled Quality and Testable Code](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B412)

Comment: Why don't you have two registrations? The first of `IUserManager` to `UserManager` and the second of `IUnitOfWork` to `UnitOfWork`. I personally don't use AutoFac but any container should resolve recursively so that when it resolves the UserManager it will automatically use UnitOfWork registration.

Answer (score 2):

When using IOC container you have to register all your services in the container. When a service is requested, this is the responsibility of the container to create the graph of needed services.

You can register both services like this :

```
builder.RegisterType<UserManager>().As<IUserManager>();
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>();
```

The `WithParameter` method is usefull for some requirement, for example when you need some parameters from configuration to create an instance :

```
builder.RegisterType<XService>()
       .As<Service>()
       .WithParameter("key1", config.GetValue("key1"));
```

See [Passing parameters to Register](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/parameters.html) from the autofac documentation for more information